# Do most astronomers think that Andromeda will collide with Milky Way?

Tags: galaxy, milky-way

Most astronomers say it is likely to happen. Is this true? Are there any scientists that reject this?

Comment: Are you suggesting astronomers are not scientists?

Comment: There are, I'm sure, *scientists* that are not even aware of, and likely are completely uninterested in, the question of whether or not Andromeda and the Milky Way will collide.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a political question

Comment: It's not, that is a paranoid assumption, such an insinuation would be perfidious. it is clearly a slightly vague and unfocused phrasing. the question is obviously about measurement of galaxy motions, and it's a good question.

Comment: read the study, awesome link. it's a balance of transverse and perspective motion, to know it's trajectory. always a good excuse to see this image of the future sky: http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/files/2015/03/654291main_p1220bk.jpg

Answer (score 8):

Relatively high-resolution measurements were made with the Hubble Space Telescope over a 8 year period. From these measurements, astronomers determined that the collision was a certainty.  It is predicted to occur in about 4 billion years. I suppose there may be some astronomers who disagree with the measurements or calculations but I can find no mention of that. The results were reported in an article in "Nature" (http://www.nature.com/news/andromeda-on-collision-course-with-the-milky-way-1.10765#/b1) and published in "Astrophysical Journal"  Both are well-respected publications. The "Astrophysical Journal" reference is below.

Sangmo Tony Sohn; Jay Anderson; Roeland van der Marel (Jul 1, 2012). "The M31 velocity vector. I. Hubble Space Telescope proper-motion measurements". The Astrophysical Journal. doi:10.1088/0004-637X/753/1/7.

Comment: Just added them to answer.

Comment: Here's a nice little "You Tube" explaining how Hubble observations showed that it is coming right for us: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8YQsFZyGzw